# Catch all routes for a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an Area defined in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app. The idea for this Area is such that anything under the `/my-area` path will load the content. At this time, I have the following:

**Startup.cs**

```
...
  endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "MyArea",
    areaName: "MyArea",
    pattern: "my-area",
    defaults: new { controller="Home", action="Index" }
  );
...
```

**./Areas/MyArea/Controllers/HomeController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyOrg.MyArea.Controllers
{
  [Area("MyArea")]
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController>> logger)
    {
       _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }
  }
}
```

If I visit `https://localhost:5001/my-area` in the browser, my `Index` view successfully shows. However, when I visit `https://localhost:5001/my-area/item-a`, I receive a 404 error. I tried updating the `pattern` property on the `MapAreaControllerRoute` to be `my-area/*` however, that resulted in a 404 error for both of the URLs listed above.

How do I define a route so that anything that starts with the `/my-area` path executes the `MyOrg.MyArea.Controllers.HomeController.Index` action?

Comment: Decorate the Index Method with `[HttpGet("{item}")]` then add parameter named item of which type you wish into the Index Action

Comment: @spzvtbg I added that attribute to my `Index` action. Unfortunately, that did not work. I still receive a 404. The mapping part in my Startup.cs file currently reads:   ``` endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "MyArea",
    areaName: "MyArea",
    pattern: "my-area" + "/*",
    defaults: new { controller="Home", action="Index" }
  );```